# How to make middleware for response on all ajax requests

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, routes

I need to make a single middleware that will handle each response to web user. I try to make something like the following:

```
function ajaxResponseMiddleware(req, res, next) {
   var code = res.locals._code || 200;
   var data = res.locals._response;

   res.json(code, data);
}

app.get('/ajax1', function(req, res, next){

    // Do something and add data to be responsed
    res.locals._response = {test: "data2"};

    // Go to the next middleware 
    next();

}, ajaxResponseMiddleware);


app.get('/ajax2', function(req, res, next){

    // Do something and add data to be responsed
    res.locals._response = {test: "data2"};
    res.locals._code = 200;

    // Go to the next middleware 
    next();

}, ajaxResponseMiddleware);
```

The response is handled in ajaxResponseMiddleware function where I can add some default state for all my ajax responses.

One thing that I don't like in the approach above is the adding ajaxResponseMiddleware function in each route.

So what do you think about this approach? May you advise improvements or share your experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

middleware is just a function `function (req, res, next) {}`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// this is the middleware, you can separate to new js file if you want
function jsonMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    res.json_v2 = function (code, data) {
        if(!data) {
            data = code;
            code = 200;
        }
        // place your modification code here
        //
        //
        res.json(code, data)
    }
    next();
}

app.use(jsonMiddleware); // Note: this should above app.use(app.router)
app.use(app.router);

app.get('/ajax1', function (req, res) {
    res.json_v2({
        name: 'ajax1'
    })
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: But how it will works when I handle error like 

if (err) {
    return next(err)
}

?

Comment: when a middleware is called that mean there no err happend before. And if an err is happend inside jsonMiddleware just call return next(err)

Comment: Ok. Thanks you very much for the answer but maybe better add json_v2 function into locals instead res object?

Comment: locals is for send params from controller to views (render like jade or ejs), so if you do not call that function in render you should not assign to locals. As I see, you call that function in controller.

Comment: I'm just afraid to override any method of res object

Comment: It is very very important to know: you SHOULD NOT assign a variable to locals if it is unnecessary, because this will destroy cache control of express framework. because express use locals to know it should re-render template again or not, it should send HTML to browser or tell browser that the content is not modify via code: 304 instead of 200

Comment: Omg. Thanks for that note. I really don't known about it and thank you very much for the response again.